# React Native Client for Google Maps Services, how to use this kind of .. functions?

Tags: react-native, functional-programming

I'm trying to learn react-native functional but with all the different flavors this has been quite a challenging learning curve in which I mostly have difficulties finding the right question to search for.
The project I'm building needs google maps and some related APIs so I found [this project](https://github.com/hysan/react-native-google-maps-services/tree/master) but I don't understand how to use it.

The docs give the following example :

```
    var googleMapsClient = require('react-native-google-maps-services').createClient({
      key: 'your API key here'
    });

    Make requests to the Google Maps APIs by calling methods on the client object.

    // Geocode an address.
    googleMapsClient.geocode({
      address: '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA'
    }, function(err, response) {
      if (!err) {
        console.log(response.json.results);
      }
    });
```

with the above example I do get the response from the console.log in the terminal but I cant get it out to use in the rest of my code.

I assume the reason this is not documented in the specs is because it's so basic but after searching for hours I could use some help with an example or just by pointing me to what I should be searching for.

What I tried:

```
    import {GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY} from '@env';

    var googleMapsClient =
    require('react-native-google-maps-services').createClient({
        key: `${GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}`,
    });

    function Libtest() {
    // Geocode an address.
    const test = googleMapsClient.geocode(
        {
        address: '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA',
        },
        function (err, response) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log('inFunctionLog: =>', response.json.results); //<= info is available here
        }
        },
    );
    //HOW DO I ACCESS THE RESPONSE OUTSIDE OF THE FUNCTION? ALL FAILS
    console.log('get response: => ', googleMapsClient());
    console.log('get response2: => ', test.response.json.results);
    console.log('get response3: => ', test);
    console.log('get response4: => ', googleMapsClient.geocode.response.results);
    }

    export default Libtest;
```

Many thanks!

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: The results are in `response` that is populated by `googleMapsClient.geocode()`. You see what they contain as they are printed to the console. You access the results by using `response.json.results` - read that instead of just logging it to the console.

Comment: thx but how do I read "response.json.results". every attempt I made to get this value outside of the function results in errors. I tried to set it in a state but then the code circles indifinetely. From my research I assume this kind of function is called a "callback" function?

Comment: I'm trying to use the output of the googleMapsClient but I don't understand how to access it's value outside the function. e.g. how could I print the value of "response.results" in a view? or just console.log it but outside the googleMapsClient.geocode({..

Comment: It seems that the library do the work as expected while you have a challenge with displaying response result within the app. I have free time we can chat and help you to figure it out.

Comment: Thx for the feedback. I'm not sure we are on the same timezone so I updated the question with my attempts. If you could point me how to make my example work?

Answer (score 0):

The keyword I was missing was "callback function". this is how I got wat I wanted refactoring the callback to an async function (which how I understood it is a prefered approach vs callback functions). Still learning so if this is not the best way plz advise:

```
  const googleMapsClient =
    require('react-native-google-maps-services').createClient({
      key: `${GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}`,
      Promise: Promise,
    });

  const GetDistance = () => {
    const [info, setInfo] = useState(null);

    // distance between addresses with a promise
    useEffect(() => {
      const GetDistanceAsync = async () => {
        try {
          googleMapsClient
            .distanceMatrix({
              origins: 'Ukkelse Steenweg 110, 1650 Beersel, Belgium',
              destinations: 'Brusselsesteenweg 33, 1652 Beersel, Belgium',
            })
            .asPromise()
            .then(response => {
              console.log('infunction', response.json);
              setInfo(response.json);
            });
        } catch (err) {
          console.log('err', err);
        }
      };
      GetDistanceAsync();
    }, []);

    console.log('exFunction', info);
```